# redirect download directory to subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

my download script structure is:

```
http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/**/**
```

now i want move and redirect to subdomain

for example

redirect

```
http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/61/4249
 to
http://www.alt.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/61/4249
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/53/824
 to
http://www.alt.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/53/824
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either mod_alias:

```
Redirect /download/viewdownload http://www.alt.mysite.com/download/viewdownload
```

In the vhost config or htaccess in the document root of the `www.mysite.com` host, or use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?download/viewdownload/(.*)$ http://www.alt.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/$1 [L,R]
```